# How to cite an item in the appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I want to put a list of items in the appendix and then cite the items in the main text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}

Citing appendix section (\ref{sec:appendix:A})

Autoref citing appendix section (\autoref{sec:appendix:A})

Citing an item under appendix setcion A (\ref{figure::appendix::1})

Autoref citing an item under appendix setcion A (\autoref{figure::appendix::1})

\appendix
\appendixpage

\section{A section}
\label{sec:appendix:A}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1 \label{figure::appendix::1}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the first item in the appendix A is cited as 1 or item 1, how to make it shown as something like Appendix A.1 or A.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to redefine `\theenumi` upon entering the appendix part of the document:

```
\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesection.\arabic{enumi}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
\ref{sec:appendix:A} & Cross-reference an appendix section \\
\autoref{sec:appendix:A} & Autoref-crossreference an appendix section \\
\ref{item:app:b:2} & Cross-reference an item under appendix section B \\
\autoref{item:app:b:2} & Autoref-crossreference an item under appendix section B 
\end{tabular}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\renewcommand\theenumi{\thesection.\arabic{enumi}}

\section{A section}
\label{sec:appendix:A}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1 \label{figure::appendix::1}
\end{enumerate}

\section{B section}
\label{sec:appendix:B}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1 
  \item Item 2 \label{item:app:b:2}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```